# ERROR/StatusBarPolicy(1526) when running cordova 3.1.0 on samsung galaxy pocket

Tags: android, cordova

I am currently using Cordova 3.1.0.
When I debug my application on my Samsung Galaxy Pocket the following error keeps appearing in the log:

```
11-27 08:40:46.132: ERROR/StatusBarPolicy(1526): ecio: 27
11-27 08:40:46.132: ERROR/StatusBarPolicy(1526): iconLevel: 4
```

Any ideas what this can be and how I can get rid of it.